# Create Column Chart from Pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am trying to create Column Chart from Pivot table.

I am able to generate the Pivot table from my code by recording the macros.

I tried in the same way to generate the Chart by recording the macros, but it was confusing.

So, I tried my own code, I am not successful. Could anyone suggest how i could generate an Chart from Pivot table,

Below is the code used for generating the Pivot table

```
Sub AutoPivot()

Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim pvtsht              As Worksheet

' set Pivot Cache for Pivot Table
' Your range is static, there are ways to refer to a dynamic range
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Preparation sheet!R1C1:R1048576C8")

' set the Pivot table's sheet
Set pvtsht = Worksheets("CAT_Pivot")


' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = pvtsht.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' check if "PivotTable7" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' Pivot table object is nothing >> create it            
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "PivotTable4" sheet
    Set PvtTbl = pvtsht.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=pvtsht.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Colour"), "Count of Colour", xlCount

      With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Category")
          .Orientation = xlRowField
          .Position = 1
      End With
      With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Colour")
          .Orientation = xlColumnField
          .Position = 1
      End With
      With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Category")
          .PivotItems("DG").Visible = False
          .PivotItems("DG").Visible = False
          .PivotItems("DG-Series").Visible = False
          .PivotItems("gn").Visible = False
          .PivotItems("yl").Visible = False
          .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
      End With
      With PvtTbl.PivotFields("Colour")
          .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
      End With
Else
     ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
     PvtTbl.ChangePivotCache PvtCache
     PvtTbl.RefreshTable        
End If

End Sub
```

Below is the code, i used for generating the Chart from Pivot table.

```
Sub Autochart()

    Dim chobj As ChartObject        
    Dim ch As Chart        
    Dim pvtsht As Worksheet

    Set pvtsht = Sheets("CAT_Pivot")        
    Set chobj = pvtsht.ChartObjects.Add(300, 200, 550, 200)        
    '300 left, 220 top, 550 width, 200 height

    Set ch = chobj.Chart        
    ch.SetSourceData pt.PvtTbl        
    ch.ChartType = xlColumn        
    chobj.Name = "EChart1"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set the `ChartObject.Chart.SetSourceData`, you need to set it to the `TableRange2` of your desired `PivotTable`.

Also, since this is a new `sub`, it doesn't recognize the local variable `PvtTbl` you have `Set` in `Sub AutoPivot`, so you need to `Set` it again in this `Sub`.

Last, there is no chart type `xlColumn`, you need to select one from the available valid options, suce as `xlColumnClustered` or `xlColumnStacked`, etc.

***Code***

```
Sub Autochart()

Dim chtObj      As ChartObject
Dim PvtSht      As Worksheet
Dim PvtTbl      As PivotTable

' set the Pivot sheet
Set PvtSht = Sheets("CAT_Pivot")

' set the Pivot Table object
Set PvtTbl = PvtSht.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

' set the Chart Object
Set chtObj = PvtSht.ChartObjects.Add(300, 200, 550, 200)

' modify ChartObject properties
With chtObj
    .Chart.SetSourceData PvtTbl.TableRange2 ' set the chart's data range to the Pivot-Table's TableRange2
    .Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .Name = "EChart1"
End With

End Sub
```